# How to remove unfinished Boot Camp Partition?

Tags: bootcamp, partition

When I tried to create a new partition using Boot Camp it suddenly crashed and my computer restarted. Apparently the partition was created because the 50GB I specified during creation are gone from my HDD but the partition never got registered. How can I remove the partition and begin from scratch?

Comment: Does the 50GB partition show up in Disk Utility or in Boot Camp Assistant?

Comment: @Justwes I managed to repair it with Disk Utility, but the partition hangs in the middle of the partition when executed form the Boot Camp Assistant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to boot from your Mac OS X Install CD and edit the partitions using the Disk Utility (found in the menu). This can be very handy for removing partitions that just won't die.

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how I can create a partition without Mac OS X crashing on me. :(